# Issue taking repeated scanner input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm making a dungeon exploring type game where the user can enter input as one move each turn (choosing a single direction to move). However, I am encountering a problem with taking Scanner input. When I test my method a single time it works correctly, however when I put it into a while loop so that I can get a new move from the player each turn, I am getting an error after the first input. I can't figure out why I am getting this error, since shouldn't it just be scanning for new input each time it runs? Thanks for any insight.

The error is as follows:

```
Enter your move: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at ActTwoGame.Update(ActTwoGame.java:63)
    at ActTwoGame.main(ActTwoGame.java:42)
```

Here is the code in question:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DungeonGame {
    // Data to display the base geometry in the room
    // When drawing on the screen the orientation will be flipped
    // This is fine, since we'll fix it later
    private static final int roomData[][] = {   
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},                                  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};

        private static int xPos = 1;
        private static int yPos = 15;

    // Tiles
    private static final String WALL_GRAPHIC = "##";
    private static final String BLANK_GRAPHIC = "..";   
    private static final String PLAYER_GRAPHIC = "!!";  

    public static String map = new String();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Start();        

        while (true)
        {
            Draw();
            Update();
        }

    }


    public static void Start()
    {
    // Init logic
        System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to Act Two: The Game.");
        System.out.println("To control your player, use the WASD keys. You will be prompted for input, but you can");
        System.out.println("only move one space per turn. Enter W for up, S for left, A for down, D for right.\n");
    }

    public static void Update() {
            // Gameplay logic
        String charMoves = "";
        Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your move: ");
        charMoves = scanLine.next();


        if (charMoves.equals("w") || charMoves.equals("W")) {
            if (roomData[xPos-1][0] != 1) 
                xPos -= 1;
            else
                System.out.println("Ouch! That was a wall.");


        }
        else if (charMoves.equals("a") || charMoves.equals("A")) {
            if (roomData[yPos-1][0] != 1) 
                yPos -= 1;
            else
                System.out.println("Ouch! That was a wall.");

        }
        else if (charMoves.equals("s") || charMoves.equals("S")) {
            if(roomData[xPos+1][0] != 1)
                xPos += 1;
            else
                System.out.println("Ouch! That was a wall.");


        }
        else if (charMoves.equals("d") || charMoves.equals("D")) {
            if (roomData[yPos+1][0] != 1)
                yPos += 1;
            else
                System.out.println("Ouch! That was a wall.");


        }
        else
            System.out.println("Invalid move. No action was taken.");
        scanLine.close();
    }

    public static void Draw() {
            // Map drawing

        for (int i = 0; i < roomData.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < roomData[0].length; j++) {
                if (roomData[i][j] == 1)
                    map += (WALL_GRAPHIC);
                else if (i == yPos && j == xPos)
                    map += (PLAYER_GRAPHIC);
                else
                    map += (BLANK_GRAPHIC);
                }
            map += "\n";
            } 
        System.out.println(map);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be closing the  scanLine object insided `update` method

```
scanLine.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't think about that.